# Asp.net DMS/CMS package/module for existing asp.net membership site?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, opencms, dms

Can anyone recommend a reasonably extensible asp.net CMS/DMS package or module that can be readily integrated into an existing c# Asp.net site (not MVC) with an existing forms authenticated membership via the membership provider and tables?

Many thanx in advance for any tips/suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at both [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) and [N2](http://n2cms.com/), and they both use the standard ASP.NET role and membership providers. They're both open source and high quality. N2 is a little more barebones though.

Comment: Thanks shea I'm looking at both now, but i'm not seeing the DMS part in N2. Just read a scathing review of umbraco, dogging both their file management and their implementation of asp.net membership:

http://www.opensourcec.org/blogs/bill_bosacker/archive/2009/07/24/4391.aspx 

Also, my project's commercial, so the licensing fee is a question; thanks 4 your suggestions!

Comment: To be honest, I'd never heard the term DMS until I looked it up just now. I'm probably not your guy for an answer on that functionality. As for the review, I wouldn't put too much faith in any one article.